# How does the syntax `new Class[]{}` work?

Tags: java, reflection

In the first code example of this [beginners guide to Dependency Injection](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321158/A-beginners-guide-to-Dependency-Injection) I encountered some new constructs of which I am not sure that I totally understand:

```
 // Instantiate CabAgency, and satisfy its dependency on an airlineagency.

 Constructor constructor = cabAgencyClass.getConstructor
  (new Class[]{AirlineAgency.class});
 cabAgency = (CabAgency) constructor.newInstance
  (new Object[]{airlineAgency});
```

What does `new Class[]{AirlineAgency.class}` actually mean and do?

I understand that its goal is to create a `Constructor` instance for `AirlineAgency.class` but how does the syntax `new Class[]{}` achieve this?

Why the array notion `[]` when there is only one object involved?

What is the `{}` syntax here? Why not `()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`new Class[] { AirlineAgency.Class }` creates an one-element array of `Class` objects and initializes the only element to be `AirlineAgency.class`. It is similar to `new int[] { 42 }`.

The code is essentially equivalent to this:

```
Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[1];
parameterTypes[0] = AirlineAgency.class;

Constructor constructor = cabAgencyClass.getConstructor(parameterTypes);

Object[] arguments = new Object[1];
arguments[0] = airlineAgency;

cabAgency = (CabAgency)constructor.newInstance(arguments);
```

The [`Class.getConstructor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) method wants an array of parameter types for the constructor (to find the right overload to use), and similarly [`Constructor.newInstance`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) wants an array of arguments. That's why it's done that way.

Comment: That's the best answer I could have ever expected. Thank you! +1

Comment: The name of this construct is 'anonymous array initialization'.